# Deeplearning with Python Tensorflow,Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am writing masters thesis about deeplearning and have a problem probably about library.

Below is the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2' has no attribute '__internal__'
```

Model:

```
import tensorflow 
from tensorflow import  keras 
from keras import models  
from keras import layers  
model = models.Sequential()  
model.add(layers.Dense(32, input_shape=(784,)))  
model.add(layers.Dense(32))
```

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow are you using? Its probably not compatible with the Keras version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem lies in the way you are importing the modules you need. Try to do this way:

```
import tensorflow  
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers  

model = models.Sequential()   
model.add(layers.Dense(32, input_shape=(784,)))   
model.add(layers.Dense(32))

model.summary()
```

If you get the summary of your network it means that everything is working fine, otherwise it could me that you haven't installed Tensorflow properly.

For reference this is the summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 32)                25120
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 32)                1056
=================================================================
Total params: 26,176
Trainable params: 26,176
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: No, this is not the cause of the problem, it is incompatibility between Keras and TensorFlow versions.

Answer (score 0):

most likely is the version of tensorflow you are using
You just need to uninstall all keras and tensorflow packages and install the versions supported by Retinanet.

!pip uninstall keras -y
!pip uninstall keras-nightly -y
!pip uninstall keras-Preprocessing -y
!pip uninstall keras-vis -y
!pip uninstall tensorflow -y

!pip install tensorflow==2.3.0
!pip install keras==2.4

Just add this to the top of your colab notebook and restart your runtime once its completed and then you are good to go